# Convert Flash SWF to Video File Format (e.g AVI) on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, swf

I want to convert the SWF Flash with Audio file to Video File (AVI).  I do not use Adobe Flash Editor.  Is there stand alone SWF converter software for MacOSX?

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for [Evom](http://thelittleappfactory.com/evom/).

Answer (score 0):

you can try stuff like mencode of ffmpegx to convert an swf to a video.  sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't.

personally i just pop open screenflow run the swf full screen and screen record it then save it to whatever format i want..  quicktime for snow leopard can also screen record but you'll have the cursor in your movie.